# Getting cURL 26 error while using Facebook Ads API to create ad image

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am using PHP sdk for connecting to Facebook Ads.

Version details - "facebook/php-business-sdk": "^14.0.0"

I am using the Facebook Ads API: API Link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-image/ to create a new ad image for a given advertiser ID in my PHP code.
However, when I run the code, I get the following error:
curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application
I am struggling to fix it. Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
$formatted_params['image_url'] = "https://res.cloudinary.com/{further_image_path}";
$image_params['filename'] = $formatted_params['image_url'];
$image = (new AdAccount('act_'.(string) $this->advertiser_id))->CreateAdimage( [], $image_params );
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

PS - I have also checked and I can open cloudinary URL from the browser when I paste it in the address bar so there does not seems to be an issue with wrong URL etc.

Comment: Not sure you can use a URL, have you tried a local file name?

Comment: Sure will try the local file.

Comment: local file name worked. Thanks!